# Windows Height - 140 pixels

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello I am trying to get the height of the browser window and minus the header.

I tried the following however it does not work:

```
  var wheight = $(window).height() - 140;

  $(window).resize(function() {
    wheight = $(window).height() - 140;
    $('.slide').css({"height":slideHeight+"px"});
  });
```

It works fine if I dont try to minus the 140px.

Any ideas?

Comment: What doesn't work about it?  Where do you use `wheight`? What is `slideHeight`?

Comment: I should really check my code carefully. slideHeight was replaced with wheight :) I forgot i renamed that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want this:

```
 $(window).resize(function() {
    wheight = $(window).height() - 140;
    $('.slide').css({"height":wheight +"px"});
  });
```